# Entity Framework request is slow with date parameter vs SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I'm in trouble with a simple entity request. I have tried a lot of things to improve its performance, and I can't find any solution. All the request have been tested with the same parameter date, and all the requests return exactly the same data. I also precise that the lazy loading is not in cause, the `ToList()` in the request is to test the request performance.

Here the original request in entity:

```
var T = base.Context.Readings
                    .Where(r => r.ReadOn >= pFrom && r.ReadOn <= pTo)
                    .Select(x => x.BatchDetail.Species)
                    .Distinct().ToList();
```

To resume I want to check the readings with dates, then take the species object in their `BatchDetails`.

The SQL query for this request is:

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[Species_ID] AS[ID],
    [Distinct1].[Code] AS[Code],
    [Distinct1].[Name] AS[Name]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         [Extent2].[Species_ID] AS[Species_ID],
         [Extent3].[Code] AS[Code],
         [Extent3].[Name] AS[Name],
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Readings] AS[Extent1]
     INNER JOIN
         [dbo].[BatchDetails] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BatchDetail_ID] = [Extent2].[idBatchDetail]
     INNER JOIN
         [dbo].[Species] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Species_ID] = [Extent3].[idSpecies]
     WHERE
         ([Extent1].[ReadOn] >= @p0) AND([Extent1].[ReadOn] <= @p1)
) AS [Distinct1]
```

If I execute the Entity Framework request, I get a respones within 5 seconds.

If I execute the SQL request on SQL Server by replacing @p0 and @p1 by '2021-01-01 hh:mm:ss' (the date), it is only 0.4 seconds.

I also tried to do this:

```
    var sqlP1 = new SqlParameter();
    sqlP1.ParameterName = "@p0";
    sqlP1.Value = pFrom;
    sqlP1.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    sqlP1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    var sqlP2 = new SqlParameter();
    sqlP2.ParameterName = "@p1";
    sqlP2.Value = pTo;
    sqlP2.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    sqlP2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    var Z = base.Context.Species.SqlQuery(@"SELECT 
            [Distinct1].[Species_ID] AS[ID],
            [Distinct1].[Code] AS[Code],
            [Distinct1].[Name] AS[Name]
            FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
                [Extent2].[Species_ID] AS[Species_ID],
                [Extent3].[Code] AS[Code],
                [Extent3].[Name] AS[Name],
                FROM[dbo].[Readings] AS[Extent1]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[BatchDetails] AS[Extent2] ON[Extent1].[BatchDetail_ID] = [Extent2].[idBatchDetail]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[Species] AS[Extent3] ON[Extent2].[Species_ID] = [Extent3].[idSpecies]
                WHERE([Extent1].[ReadOn] >= @p0) AND([Extent1].[ReadOn] <= @p1)
            )  AS[Distinct1]
            ", sqlP1 , sqlP2 ).ToList();
```

This also takes 5 seconds (like the first execution).

And this:

```
    var Z = base.Context.Species.SqlQuery(@"SELECT 
            [Distinct1].[Species_ID] AS[ID],
            [Distinct1].[Code] AS[Code],
            [Distinct1].[Name] AS[Name]
            FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
                [Extent2].[Species_ID] AS[Species_ID],
                [Extent3].[Code] AS[Code],
                [Extent3].[Name] AS[Name],
                FROM[dbo].[Readings] AS[Extent1]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[BatchDetails] AS[Extent2] ON[Extent1].[BatchDetail_ID] = [Extent2].[idBatchDetail]
                INNER JOIN[dbo].[Species] AS[Extent3] ON[Extent2].[Species_ID] = [Extent3].[idSpecies]
                WHERE([Extent1].[ReadOn] >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00') AND([Extent1].[ReadOn] <= '2022-07-01 00:00:00')
            )  AS[Distinct1]
      ).ToList();
```

this one is 0.4 sec (like the request in SQL Server).

I saw that entity could have some troubles with format conversion (I saw it for `varchar` and `nvarchar`), but I don't understand why, if I pass the date in param in the request, it takes 10x more time than passing them in string in the request.

Do you have an explanation? Or do you have any idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also tried `WithNoTracking` but there is no change in the performances.

Comment: Add `AsNoTracking()` to see if that changes the execution time. If so then the performance is the DbContext tracking the returned entities. If it makes no difference you need to use Sql Profiler and capture the Query Execution Plan and compare it to the one in SSMS.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried it, and no change.

Comment: Ok. It could also be parameter sniffing that is causing the problem seeing as how the same query with and without parameters have different execution times. See also https://www.google.com/search?q=parameter+sniffing+sql+server. To test this add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query with parameters, is it fast(er) now?

Comment: Well I think it could be something like that, but I don't know what to do to face it ^^

Comment: Add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the slow query to see if that fixes it. This is meant as a diagnostic to see if this is indeed the issue.

Comment: The usual suspects, add appropriate indexes, fix index fragmentation, calculate statistics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/start-and-use-the-database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: If all requests were slow, I would suspect the indexes. But there one is very fast and not the other

Comment: So did `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` make a difference?

Comment: Different copies of even an identical query can get and keep a different plan (using a different index, or the same index in a different way, based on things that might have been different at compilation time), even more so if the queries are _not_ identical. Don't just wave away suggestions because you assume they should behave identically (also parameters <> variables). See [Slow in the application, fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) and [Multiple Plans for an "Identical" Query](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query).