# EF ExecuteFunction takes more time than running the same query on SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem executing a stored procedure with Entity Framework on .Net:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
           .ObjectContext
           .ExecuteFunction<ReportsRevenuePayMents_DataTables_Result> 
                ("ReportsRevenuePayMents_DataTables",
                ignorar_primerosParameter,
                cantidad_filasParameter,
                filerParameter,
                startDateParameter,
                endDateParameter,
                property_IDParameter,
                sales_Status_IDParameter,
                departmentKeyParameter);
```

It takes a lot of time and so I get the error "TimeOut Execution..."

But the issue here is that if I execute that stored procedure directly in SQL Server, it only takes 4 seconds to execute succesfully.

Why does it take so much time to execute with the above code on .Net EF?

Comment: See [the comment thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73253756/61305).

Comment: What happens if you execute that stored procedure in SQL Server when `set arithabort off` is in effect? Is it still 4 seconds, or is it now > 30 seconds?